# How do I make an if statement for 3 variables?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

I have had some problems with some code I have but I have managed to source the problem and I have nearly found a way to fix it. When I change the number at the end of maximum_guesses to maximum_guesses1, maximum_guesses2 and maximum_guesses3 the code works fine. However, when I have duplicated it and changed the number at the end of the maximum_guessses the number of guesses count as three when it should only be one.

How do I make the code below work for all three maximum_guesses?

maximum_guesses1, maximum_guesses2, maximum_guesses3

```
number_of_guesses++; 
if (number_of_guesses > maximum_guesses3)
{
window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses!");
return;
}

number_of_guesses++; 
if (number_of_guesses > maximum_guesses2)
{
window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses!");
return;
}

number_of_guesses++; 
if (number_of_guesses > maximum_guesses1)
{
window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses!");
return;
}
```

I need to put all three of the above into one piece of code. maximum_guesses1 stops at 45 guesses, maximum_guesses2 stops at 40 and maximum_guesses3 stops at 35 but when I have put them together they dont stop.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: I have edited the question with the three parts that I am trying to merge into one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might want to do is separate this out to a different function, your functions should have namespaces to architect your application. You can do this with a helper lib found [here](https://github.com/outworkers/dali).

You could try refactor code to something a little more structured like so:

**module-controller.js**

```
dali.util.namespace('myCompany.myApp.module');

myCompany.myApp.module.ClassName = function(maxGuesses) {
  this.maxGuesses = maxGuesses;
  this.numberOfGuesses = 0;
  this.alertMessage = 'Sorry, you have run out of guesses!';
};

myCompany.myApp.module.ClassName.prototype.hasMoreGuessesLeft = function() {
  return this.numberOfGuesses < maxGuesses;
};

myCompany.myApp.module.ClassName.prototype.guess = function(guess) {
  this.numberOfGuesses++;

  if(this.hasMoreGuessesLeft()) {
    //do something with the guess?
    console.log(guess);
  } else {
    window.alert(this.alertMessage + ' - ' + this.maxGuesses + ' max.');
  }
};
```

use it (import module-controller.js):

```
var maximum_guesses1 = 10;
var instance = new myCompany.myApp.module.ClassName(maximum_guesses1);
var guessAmount = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < guessAmount; i++) {
  instance.guess('Ive guessed ' + i + ' time(s)');
}
```

You can then pass in `maximum_guesses1`, `maximum_guesses2`, `maximum_guesses3` accordingly.

I hope this helps.

Rhys

Comment: I have just tried your suggestion it now makes each one of my maximum_guesses stop at 34. maximum_guesses1 should stop at 45, maximum_guesses2 should stop at 40 and maximum_guesses3 should stop at 35.

Comment: I have just tried that but now when I press my button to guess nothing happens. Thanks anyway

Comment: Please examine what my code is doing, and understand that from your vaguely asked question, this is the best I can do for you. I have tried to show you some OO JS concepts with this also.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m3Pbm41n This is everything I have so far. It is in 3 sections the first part is a game introduction that has radio buttons for each difficulty. The second part is the game itself and lastly is the minefield.js where the problem is. When I change the maximum_guesses1 to 2 or 3 it works exactly how I want it to. The only problem I have is trying to put them together, when I do that now it ignores whatever difficulty has been selected and goes straight to 45. Easy is 45 guesses, intermediate is 40 guesses and advanced is 35 guesses.

Comment: Try using console.log(variableName) along your code and using google chrome developer console to help debug

Comment: My code has been updated. I forgot the `new` operator

Comment: I have tried your updated code but when I press the fire button on the game nothing happens. The code I have works I just need to make the difficulty part work. I need to merge 3 maximum_guesses into one

Comment: Its not always about copy and pasting, please interpret my code and then see how yours differs

Comment: Both codes are completely different. I'm not familiar with the code you have put as I am new to javascript. There must be a way of putting the code below as one so it works properly?                                                     number_of_guesses++;
 if (number_of_guesses > maximum_guesses3)
 {
 window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses!");
 return;
 }
 if (number_of_guesses > maximum_guesses2)
 {
 window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses!");
 return;
 }
 if (number_of_guesses > maximum_guesses1)
 {
 window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses!");
 return;
 }

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) to solve this problem.

For example, your solution might look like this (if I understood you correctly):

```
number_of_guesses++; 
if ( number_of_guesses > maximum_guesses1 ||
     number_of_guesses > maximum_guesses2 ||
     number_of_guesses > maximum_guesses3 ) {
  window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses!");
  return;
}
```

Comment: I have just tried this but all my guesses went to 45 guesses when they should stop. maximum_guesses1 should stop at 45, maximum_guesses2 at 40 and maximum_guesses3 should stop at 35.

Comment: You have reminded me of something I have previously seen though.

Comment: Try to use `&&` instead of `||`.